# buildozer issues on mac

Tags: android, python, osx-snow-leopard, kivy

I'm a hobbyist when it comes to the world of programming so I am in no way a seasoned expert so please be kind and gentle, I'm only here to learn.

OK so the issue I'm having is with buildozer on Mac OSX. It's having a hard time compiling an apk for android.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.8, Kivy 1.7.1, the latest Cython, ActivePython 2.7.2.

When I run the 'buildozer android debug' command in the app directory it begins to process however then runs into an error and ceases.

The following is what's logged in the Terminal window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.17', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 961, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 157, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 394, in install_platform
    self._install_android_packages()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 350, in _install_android_packages
    self._android_update_sdk('tools,platform-tools')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 309, in _android_update_sdk
    index = child.expect([EOF, '[y/n]: '])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/libs/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/libs/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/libs/pexpect.py", line 1378, in expect_loop
    c = self.read_nonblocking (self.maxread, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/libs/pexpect.py", line 837, in read_nonblocking
    self.logfile.write (s.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 760: invalid continuation byte
```

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Many Thanks

Tj

Comment: Try buildozer --verbose android debug. It might provide some helpful info.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, join the kivy users support google group. Just google for it.

Comment: Hi Totem I have tried that and gives me the same print in the terminal. Thanks for the suggestion I'll try and scour the kivy users support group for resolutions and share my findings

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found an answer yet. I was having a similar issue and an upgrade from the git repository resolved it:

```
pip install --upgrade git+http://github.com/kivy/buildozer
```